# Am I allowed to stay in Singapore when Student Pass expires?

Tags: study, singapore

I have just graduated and my Student Pass is expiring soon, next month, but I have not guaranteed a job.

Can I stay in Singapore when my Student Pass expires?

Any suggestion on this situation?

Comment: What's your citizenship?

Answer (score 3):

[You are required to surrender your Student Pass when/before it expires](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/Students/Graduate/StudentServices/Immigration/Pages/ReturnSP.aspx).  If you do so in-country at the ICA, you will automatically receive a short-term visit pass (= essentially tourist visa) that lets you stay on in Singapore for a while (days or weeks, depends on your nationality).

If you want to stay for a longer period (up to a year), you can try your luck applying for a [Long-Term Visit Pass](http://www.ica.gov.sg/services_centre_overview.aspx?pageid=376).  Being a bona fide graduate of a Singaporean university and looking for work is one of the [possible criteria](http://www.ica.gov.sg/services_centre_overview.aspx?pageid=396&secid=171) for getting one.